# How to Update a Chaco Plot

Tags: python

I have a Chaco plot that I am creating and when I change one of the variables instead of updating, it draws the whole plot on top of the other plot and the plots start to stack up and overlay each other while remaining on the same window. How can I overwrite the plot instead? Note: I am changing the variable "duration" in the Foo class at the bottom. Here is my code:

```
import threading
import time
from enthought.traits.api \
import HasTraits, Int, Range, Array, Enum, on_trait_change
from enthought.traits.ui.api import View, Item
from enthought.chaco.chaco_plot_editor import ChacoPlotItem


class Hyetograph(HasTraits):
    """ Creates a simple hyetograph demo. """
    timeline = Array
    intensity = Array
    nrcs = Array
    duration = Int(12, desc='In Hours')
    year_storm = Enum(2, 10, 25, 100)
    county = Enum('Brazos', 'Dallas', 'El Paso', 'Harris')
    curve_number = Range(70, 100)
    plot_type = Enum('line', 'scatter')

    view1 = View(Item('plot_type'),
                 ChacoPlotItem('timeline', 'intensity',
                               type_trait='plot_type',
                               resizable=True,
                               x_label='Time (hr)',
                               y_label='Intensity (in/hr)',
                               color='blue',
                               bgcolor='white',
                               border_visible=True,
                               border_width=1,
                               padding_bg_color='lightgray'),
                 Item(name='duration'),
                 Item(name='year_storm'),
                 Item(name='county'))



    def calculate_intensity(self):
        """ The Hyetograph calculations. """
        # Assigning A, B, and C values based on year, storm, and county
        counties = {'Brazos': 0, 'Dallas': 3, 'El Paso': 6, 'Harris': 9}
        years = {
            2 : [65, 8, .806, 54, 8.3, .791, 24, 9.5, .797, 68, 7.9, .800],
            10: [80, 8.5, .763, 78, 8.7, .777, 42, 12., .795,81, 7.7, .753],
            25: [89, 8.5, .754, 90, 8.7, .774, 60, 12.,.843, 81, 7.7, .724],
            100: [96, 8., .730, 106, 8.3, .762, 65, 9.5, .825, 91, 7.9, .706]
        }
        year = years[self.year_storm]
        value = counties[self.county]
        a, b, c = year[value], year[value+1], year[value+2]

        self.timeline=range(2, self.duration + 1, 2)
        intensity=a / (self.timeline * 60 + b)**c
        cumdepth=intensity * self.timeline

        temp=cumdepth[0]
        result=[]
        for i in cumdepth[1:]:
            result.append(i-temp)
            temp=i
        result.insert(0,cumdepth[0])

        # Alternating block method implementation.
        result.reverse()
        switch = True
        o, e = [], []
        for i in result:
            if switch:
                o.append(i)
            else:
                e.append(i)
            switch = not switch
        e.reverse()
        result = o + e
        self.intensity = result


    def calculate_runoff(self):
        """ NRCS method to get run-off based on permeability of ground. """
        s = (1000 / self.curve_number) - 10
        a = self.intensity - (.2 * s)
        vr = a**2 / (self.intensity + (.8 * s))
        # There's no such thing as negative run-off.
        for i in range(0, len(a)):
            if a[i] <= 0:
                vr[i] = 0
        self.nrcs = vr


    @on_trait_change('duration, year_storm, county, curve_number')
    def _perform_calculations(self):
        self.calculate_intensity()
        self.calculate_runoff()


    def start(self):
        self._perform_calculations()
        self.configure_traits()


f=Hyetograph()
f.start()


# d = range(10,13)
# for n in d:
#    f.duration = n
#    time.sleep(2)



class Foo (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.__x = x
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run (self):
        print str(self.__x)
        d = range(10,13)
        for n in d:
            f.duration = n
            time.sleep(2)


Foo(1).start()
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Result of the program]

Comment: Try to make sure your indents show up correctly in the future. :)

Comment: can you also post the resulting image? it will make it easier to visualize and fix. thanks!!

Comment: Sorry about that. @user308827 Just added the picture. If you notice the y axis overlays each other making it bold and the x axis overlays itself making the letters appear twice and overlapping each other.

Comment: After updating the imports to the newest version of Chaco, traits, and traitsui (enthought.traits.ui -> traitsui, enthought.traits -> traits, enthought.chaco -> chaco), I can't reproduce the issue. Do you still see that weird overlay?